# Full screen Background Img using just CSS

Tags: html, css, image, background-image, fullscreen

SO I'm currently working on a redesign of the CSS Zengarden site.

I'm not allowed to touch or alter the HTML in any way, so all styling must being done using only CSS (so I can't create extra classes or divs).

I'm trying to create a full screen background image that isn't fixed and covers the entire first Section tag. Below is the HTML & My current css with some commented out things.

I was able to make it fullscreen, but it overlapped the other divs under it.

Is this even a possibility with the present HTML?

```
<body id="css-zen-garden">
<div class="page-wrapper">

    <section class="intro" id="zen-intro">
        <header role="banner">
            <h1>CSS Zen Garden</h1>
            <h2>The Beauty of <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> Design</h2>
        </header>

        <div class="summary" id="zen-summary" role="article">
            <p>A demonstration of what can be accomplished through <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr>-based design. Select any style sheet from the list to load it into this page.</p>
            <p>Download the example <a href="/examples/index" title="This page's source HTML code, not to be modified.">html file</a> and <a href="/examples/style.css" title="This page's sample CSS, the file you may modify.">css file</a></p>
        </div>

        <div class="preamble" id="zen-preamble" role="article">
            <h3>The Road to Enlightenment</h3>
            <p>Littering a dark and dreary road lay the past relics of browser-specific tags, incompatible <abbr title="Document Object Model">DOM</abbr>s, broken <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> support, and abandoned browsers.</p>
            <p>We must clear the mind of the past. Web enlightenment has been achieved thanks to the tireless efforts of folk like the <abbr title="World Wide Web Consortium">W3C</abbr>, <abbr title="Web Standards Project">WaSP</abbr>, and the major browser creators.</p>
            <p>The CSS Zen Garden invites you to relax and meditate on the important lessons of the masters. Begin to see with clarity. Learn to use the time-honored techniques in new and invigorating fashion. Become one with the web.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="main-supporting" id="zen-supporting" role="main">
        <div class="explanation" id="zen-explanation" role="article">
            <h3>So What is This About?</h3>
            <p>There is a continuing need to show the power of <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr>. The Zen Garden aims to excite, inspire, and encourage participation. To begin, view some of the existing designs in the list. Clicking on any one will load the style sheet into this very page. The <abbr title="HyperText Markup Language">HTML</abbr> remains the same, the only thing that has changed is the external <abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> file. Yes, really.</p>
            <p><abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr> allows complete and total control over the style of a hypertext document. The only way this can be illustrated in a way that gets people excited is by demonstrating what it can truly be, once the reins are placed in the hands of those able to create beauty from structure. Designers and coders alike have contributed to the beauty of the web; we can always push it further.</p>
        </div>
```

This is the CSS I have atm, is it possible to turn it into this (the image): http://www.bucketlistly.com/ ?

```
.intro {
  position: ;
  background-image: url(mountain-zengarden.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the help of this great tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hExwnLlj2xk

I realized that I wasn't aware of the fact that it is important to be aware of the

height of the parent divs. So in order to get the section container to fill the

whole page, I first had to set the parent container's (html, body, and outer

div) height to 100% and then it finally worked. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

Just try to add :

```
body {
    margin:0;
}

.intro {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

And then you can modify the height. So you can make a fullpage div.

Comment: and leave the rest of the CSS the same? what about the .intro class' positioning?

Comment: Have you an example of the result you want ?